# How do I configure tsc to redirect outputs to different folders?

Tags: typescript, tsc, file-structure

I'm coding a simple full-stack app with TypeScript, Express, and no framework for the front-end. Currently, my directory structure looks like this:

```
.
├── dist
├── public
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   └── index.html
└── src
    ├── client
    │   └── index.ts
    ├── server
    │   ├── api.router.ts
    │   └── index.ts
    ├── api.router.ts
    └── index.ts
```

`tsc-watch` watches changes on typescript files, compiles them and relaunches the server. Here's a script I use (from 'package.json`):

```
"dev": "./node_modules/.bin/tsc-watch src/server/*.ts --onSuccess \"node ./dist/index.js\""
```

The problem is: when I run the script, it compiles the client code (from `src/client/index.ts`) and outputs it to `dist/client/index.js`, but I actually want it in `public/scripts/index.js` so that I could serve it with the `.html` file. Additionally, I don't want to relaunch the server when I modify client code, only when I modify the server code. How do I go about it?

Is it even the right strategy for managing the file structure?

Comment: Maybe you could add a copy or move command before `node ./dist/index.js`, using `&&`

Comment: @Cem that could work, I'll give it a shot. Sounds kind of hacky though, there gotta be a built-in option in `tsc` for that...